# Google Sheets - if function

Tags: google-sheets

I have a spreadsheet that I use to track all of our mortgage closings. On some of the closings, I make a bonus depending on who the referral source was. I would like to have a column labeled "Bonus" and next to each row, it would either say "Yes" or "No" depending on whether or not I earn that bonus. Since the bonus is determined by the referral source, I would like a formula that you could use multiple "Ifs" to search. For example: =if(B:B = "John Smith" "Mary Jones" "Janice Green", "YES", "NO"). So the concept is, if any name in column B says any one of these three names, a YES would populate. Otherwise, it will say NO, if one of these names are not listed. Make sense?

Comment: Have you tried what you've described? What does it look like? What goes wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You can add more or'd terms as you please.

```
=ArrayFormula(IF(REGEXMATCH($B:$B,"(?i)(Name1|Name2|Name3)"),"Yes","No"))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `OR` operator.

```
=IF(OR($B:$B="Name1",$B:$B="Name2",$B:$B="Name3"),"Yes","No")
```